# How can I fix this: ValueError invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''? Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, valueerror

```
import os
txt_file = 'highscore.txt'
score = total_points

if not os.path.exists(txt_file):
    with open(txt_file, 'w') as f:
        f.write('Score: {score}\n'
                + 'Name: {name}')

with open(txt_file, 'r') as f:
    previous_score = int(f.readline().split()[-1])

# compare the previous score with current score and write the highest score
if previous_score < score:
    with open(txt_file, 'w') as f:
        f.write(f'Score: {score}\n'
                + f'Name: {name}')
```

I understand that because I have `Score:` on the line, it isn't coming back as just the score. If I use `re.findall` I can get just the score but it turns into a list, and I still can't use `int(previous_score) < int(score)`. How do I go about making this work?

Thank you to the previous commenter, Sachin, who helped me get this far by the way.

edit:
I managed to get it with all of your help. Thank you so much!

Comment: The error message is telling you that you are calling `int('')`. It's not clear that you are actually reading a line from your file.

Comment: First, why do you use int(previous_score) when it is a line such as 'Score: {score}'. And then, secondly, why are you saving it like this? Shouldn't you use f-strings or string.format?

Comment: It is not clear what you write `'Score: {score}\n'`, do you mean you have a variable `score`? Use `f'Score: {score}\n'` then

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean with your last sentence. Could you provide an example?

Comment: I added ```f'Score: {score}'```. Thank you. I'm still getting this ```ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '{score}'``` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what's wrong with 
`previous_score = int(f.readline().split()[-1])`

Comment: You posted question as answer.

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '{score}'

Comment: The error was completely my fault. You were absolutely right. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are literally writing "Score: {score}" in the `txt_file`. You don't substitute `{score}` with the value of the variable `score`. You can open that file in an editor and confirm. To do this substitution, add `f` before each string, i.e.: your code should begin

```
with open(txt_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write(f'Score: {score}\n'
        + f'Name: {name}')
```

Then, to extract the score from `previous_score`, carefull it is the whole line, you should split the line into words and keep the last element, then convert it to integer: `int(previous_score.split()[-1])`.

Comment: Thank you for that. I'm getting this error now ```ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '{score}'```.

Comment: Did you add that f before 'Score? Also, what version of python are you using? UPDATE: Be sure to empty your file before trying again.

Comment: That was exactly my problem. Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure! If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as the solution so your question appears solved and others can find more easily.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to extract an int from a string. For example,

```
previous_score = 'Score: 150\n'             #Which you read from the file with .readline()
score          = previous_score.split()[-1] #Splits a string into words. Take last item. 
print(int(score))
```